# Searching and replacing characters with classes in R

Tags: r, regex, string, str-replace

I am trying to replace text in R. I want to find spaces between letters and numbers only and delete them, but when I search using [:alpha:] and [:alnum:] it replaces with that class operator.

```
> string <- "WORD = 500 * WORD + ((WORD & 400) - (WORD & 300))"

> str_replace_all(string,
+                 "[:alpha:] & [:alnum:]",
+                 "[:alpha:]&[:alnum:]")

[1] "WORD = 500 * WORD + ((WOR[:alpha:]&[:alnum:]00) - (WOR[:alpha:]&[:alnum:]00))"
```

How can I use the function so that it returns-

```
[1] "WORD = 500 * WORD + ((WORD&400) - (WORD&300))"
```

Comment: Why does the replacement happen with `&`, but not other operators, such as `*`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option where we match regex lookarounds to match one or more spaces (`\\s+`) either preceding or succeeding a `&` and replace with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("(?<=&)\\s+|\\s+(?=&)", "", string, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "WORD = 500 * WORD + ((WORD&400) - (WORD&300))"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace_all(string, "([:alpha:]) & ([:alnum:])", "\\1&\\2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is easy enough to handle using `sub` with lookarounds:

```
string <- "WORD = 500 * WORD + ((WORD & 400) - (WORD & 300))"
output <- gsub("(?<=\\w) & (?=\\w)", "&", string, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "WORD = 500 * WORD + ((WORD&400) - (WORD&300))"
```

Here is a brief explanation of the regex:

```
(?<=\\w)   assert that what precedes is a word character
[ ]&[ ]    then match a space, followed by `&`, followed by another space
(?=\\w)    assert that what follows is also a word character
```

Then, we replace with just a single `&`, with no spaces on either side.